# Python, List of Children

Tags: python, list, instance, python-3.8

I want to generate a parent/child datastructure in Python 3.8.10. [GCC 9.3.0] on linux The code is as simple as:

```
class Member(object):
    name = "xxx"
    parent = None
    children = []
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    
    def setParent(self,p):
        self.parent = p
        
    def addChild(self,ch):
        self.children.append(ch)
        ch.setParent(self)
        
    def myRelatives(self):
        str = "I am {0}, my parent is {1} my children are:".format(self.name,self.parent.name if self.parent is not None else "--")
        print(str)

        for ch in self.children:
            print("   {0}".format(ch.name))
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Member("A")
    B = Member("B")
    C = Member("C")
    D = Member("D")
    
    A.addChild(B)
    B.addChild(C)
    C.addChild(D)
    
    A.myRelatives()
    B.myRelatives()
    C.myRelatives()
    D.myRelatives()
```

I have expected:

```
I am A, my parent is -- my children are:
   B
I am B, my parent is A my children are:
   C
I am C, my parent is B my children are:
   D
I am D, my parent is C my children are:
```

However my output is:

```
I am A, my parent is -- my children are:
   B
   C
   D
I am B, my parent is A my children are:
   B
   C
   D
I am C, my parent is B my children are:
   B
   C
   D
I am D, my parent is C my children are:
   B
   C
   D
```

It seems the 'self.children' is used as same variable in all instances. Why and how to fix?

Thanks,
Bernd

Comment: `self.children` refers to the class variable `Member.children`, you should define `self.children` in `__init__` to create an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the attributes `name`, `parent`, and `children` in the `__init__` function, so e.g. like so:

```
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.parent = None
        self.children = list()
```

Then it should work.

EDIT:
Added improvement suggested by @chepner.

Comment: Prefer `super().__init__()` to `object.__init__(self)` unless you have a good reason to break cooperative inheritance.

Comment: Thank you Maurice, FlyingDutchman & Chepner. It works.  I'm a bit confused why  it worked in the orignal example for the variable 'Member.parent' that every instance had its own value, but didn't work for 'Children'

Comment: That would be the perfect answer.